# want to do dusk test with docker alpine

Tags: laravel-5

now trying to test laravel/dusk inside docker alpine.
but when I set up, met the following error.

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown
>   for http POST to /session with params:
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"phantomjs","platform":"ANY"}}
>
> Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused

---

source code setting is the followings.
tests/DuskTestCase.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        //static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
     protected function driver()
     {
         return RemoteWebDriver::create(
             'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::phantomjs()
         );
     }
}
```

thank you very much for reading.

Comment: How you are starting your web driver on 4444 port. Is this through docker command or docker compose. Please share the details.

Answer (score 2):

It is a combination of things really. You need to overwrite the chromedriver-linux binary that is shipped with Dusk, because it is not compatible with the alpine image. 
It should look something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
    && echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    chromium@edge \
    chromium-chromedriver@edge \
    xvfb \
    nss@edge \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /var/cache/apk/* \
    /usr/share/man \
    /tmp/*

RUN rm /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux \
&& ln -s /usr/bin/chromedriver /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux \ 
&& ln -s /usr/bin/chromium-browser /usr/bin/chrome
```

In your start.sh you use:

```
Xvfb :99 &
RUN export DISPLAY=:99
```

This will start a headless display so chrome can actually run headless inside your container.