# Artisan::call outputs php-fpm help text

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-artisan, alpine-linux

I am running a docker container based on richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest

I have laravel 5.5 perfectly running with Dusk inside it.

[want to do dusk test with docker alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259946/want-to-do-dusk-test-with-docker-alpine/52443262#52443262)

Now, in the routes, I have an Artisan::call('dusk'). This is running perfectly when doing artisan serve, but not in nginx on docker. 
"Usage: php-fpm" message shows up.

This is my location block:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         include fastcgi_params;
     }
```

It must be really simple, but I cannot figure this out, how do I get dusk being called by using an api call?

PS: this setup would allow us to do a stresstest with more then just loading pages using the Apache Benchmark tool.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out: php-fpm sets PHP_BINARY to '/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm' instead of '/usr/local/bin/php'.

Since I already was extending the duskCommand class, the fix was easy: replace the PHP_BINARY variable with the correct path. in the binary() method.